# How to add pydf to /etc/update-motd.d/10-help-text

Tags: server, motd

How is the correct way to add command `pydf` into message of the day file so I can see results of this command after login into server.

I try put

```
printf pydf
```

and

```
pydf
```

But I don't see any output.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

At least with Ubuntu 16.04 the method used to update the `/run/motd.dynamic` from the `/etc/udpate-motd.d` scripts seems to be a bit broken. The update should happen from `/etc/init/mounted-run.conf` upstart job. Since Ubuntu 16.04 does use `systemd` this upstart job is not run.

Nevertheless, I would recommend to put that into a script in `/etc/profile.d/` instead of fiddling around with the basic configuration 
in Ubuntu and break things.

```
root@xenial:~# cat /etc/profile.d/my-motd.sh 
#!/bin/sh

echo
/usr/bin/pydf
echo
```